# Need some help with GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, gui-designer

i'm working on GUI in java and got stuck with move the object.

Please visit this youtube video i made a short demo for you guys to see what i was trying to do. I'm so new to the GUI thing as i've never been taught of doing GUI.

Here is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=up1LV5r-NSg

Comment: +1 for the video & description. great idea! wish more people would do something like that.

Comment: One of the last sentences: *"I just need you now"* made me chuckle. :)

Comment: @Bart K: lolx didn't realized that, just thought it was a good song though! Although it was fitted with video, wasn't it? I do need you now to help! lolz

Comment: @james1, you're right, the song fitted perfectly with your "video-question"! I liked it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're using a GUI designer. I highly recommend building your GUI "by hand" instead in which case your code is IMO much clearer (I'm not saying all GUI designers produce bad code, but it is almost always harder to read, and editing it will be hard without using the exact same GUI designer). Once you're comfortable with GUI designing by hand, then try a GUI designer and see what makes you more comfortable.

See: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

In your case, you might create a [BorderLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), and in the "south" of your panel/frame you can place a panel with a [FlowLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) aligning it's components to the left. Then add your button to the panel with the FlowLayout.

A little demo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;

public class LayoutDemo extends JFrame {

    LayoutDemo() {
        super("LayoutDemo");
        super.setSize(400, 200);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createGUI();
        super.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        // set the layout of this frame
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // create a panel to put the button on
        final JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        // create a text area to put in the center
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

        // create the search button
        final JButton searchButton = new JButton("search");

        // add a listener to the button that add some text to the text area
        searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "pressed search on " + (new Date()) + "\n");
            }
        });

        // add the button to the bottom panel
        bottomPanel.add(searchButton);

        // wrap a scroll-pane around the text area and place it on the center of this frame
        super.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // put the bottom panel (containing the button) on the 'south' of this frame
        super.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LayoutDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

produces:

[alt text http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5874/guiq.png](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5874/guiq.png)

---

**EDIT**

And to move the button a bit more up, use the constructor `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, int hgap, int vgap)`

where `hgap` is the gap (in pixels) between the left and right components and `vgap` is the gap (in pixels) between the upper and lower components.

Try:

```
final JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 10));
```

Note that the space between the button and text area also increases slightly!

Comment: Upvoted for the BorderLayout suggestion. This is the solution I found by trial and error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889300/swing-layout-using-a-grid-while-keeping-component-dimensions

Comment: So what would you change if you wanted to move the button up alittle bit more (just alittle bit more)?

Comment: From my experience, there are almost always bugs in handwritten code. Nothing can beat NetBeans Swing GUI builder (as for Java desktop) ... It takes little effort to understand how NetBeans 'thinks', once you achieve so you'll never get corrupted code ...

Comment: @Xorty, I didn't say handwritten code is without bugs. But using a GUI designer without first knowing how to build a (simple) GUI "by hand" is IMO not the way to go. Also, a drawback of using a GUI designers is that others can't simply edit the GUI in an IDE/editor without that GUI designer.

Comment: @Bart K. - sounds better, I cancelled my downvote( edit : not really, stackoverflow wont let me atm:). As for learning - OK, as for something serious - no, never. Save your time (both for writting and debugging) and have team which knows, how to use IDE GUI designer ...

Comment: @Xorty, never did a serious GUI, but you may have a point about "serious GUIs". FYI: you can only cancel a down-vote if the answer has been edited in the mean time (no problem, just leave the down vote where it is: I have enough rep-thingies. Always have, for that matter! :)).

Comment: @Bart K: Thanks alot for your help. I think i can make GUI and move some buttons around. Is this the way you can move buttons or textbox etc.?

Comment: @james1, you can place any GUI-component on a panel. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "moving around" though. But I highly recommend you look into the tutorial about layout managers first before continuing. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

learn `fest swing  test` and miglayout! fest swing test  enables you to run your gui screnario.
and `Miglayout`,it is my opinion, also is easy to use  layout lib.

```
Fest: http://fest.easytesting.org/swing/wiki/pmwiki.php
MigLayout: http://www.miglayout.com/
```

Comment: It looks great, will try to learn this. Thanks alot

Comment: i  used them  my graduation project. The major problem of GUI development is  Layout problem. But mig enables you to make good design without any visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trying to learn the ins & outs of Java Swing and aren't trying to create some fancy GUI then a GUI designer like the one you are using should be fine.

What you are not able to do seems to be a limitation of your particular IDE though, and therefore it might be helpful to give [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) a try. You can always take the generated GUI code (ugly as it may be) and then plug it back into your project in your other IDE.

Comment: Yes, i've known that netbeans does that but i want to learn it in java and also understand the code, that's why i used that Jframe plug in thing to see how it's actually written.